# Possible to force version of dependent gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm using two gems that depend on the `faraday` gem. Unfortunately, the depend on different versions...

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In Gemfile:
    vacuum (~> 0.2) depends on
      faraday (~> 0.7.6)

    sorcery depends on
      faraday (0.8.1)
```

Is there a way to force `vacuum` to use the version of `faraday` that `sorcery` depends on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [master branch](https://github.com/hakanensari/vacuum) depends on faraday 0.8.1. Point your Gemfile at the git repo for now, and urge the author to release an updated gem to rubygems.

To answer your question for the case where the author hasn't updated, you'd have to fork the gem yourself, update the dependency in the [gemspec](https://github.com/hakanensari/vacuum/blob/master/vacuum.gemspec), and use your forked version in your app.

Comment: Is it safe just change the version number in the gemspec? I guess at least the tests should not fail.

Comment: you would need to change the version number, then rebuild the gem. If the test don't fail, hopefully you're good to go :)